# Connect to SQL Server using users in Active Directory (without Windows Authentication)

Tags: sql-server, database, ldap

I'm trying to connect SQL Server Database using the users from any open source LDAP (Open Ldap, Apache DS etc)

After going through some of the documents I found that SQL Server gives a way to connect to database using Windows User / Active Directory, but this related to Windows Authentication. What I m looking for is not Windows Authentication using SQL Server and Active Directory but authentication with Active Directory users from SQL Server without actually logging in to windows using those user details.

And Is there also a way I can achieve this with other open source ldap servers ?

Thanks.